# Executing custom scripts on microcontroller or embedded platforms

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I have a micro-controller (stm32) development board with SD Card reader. I want to build a custom LED systems where users can write simple scripts and save on the SD Card then they can select which

As a very basic example of what I am looking to do, lets say I have 2 LEDs and I would write a custom script like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
 LED_1 = ON;
 DELAY(100);
 LED_1 = OFF;
 LED_2 = ON;
 DELAY(100);
 LED_2 = OFF;
}
```

And I save this on SD Card as "script01.txt".

When users selects this file on the MCU (using LCD and buttons) then the MCU should do what is written in the script, e.g. toggling the corresponding GPIO pins and makes delays.

I believe what I am trying to do is called creating an interpreter at run-time? I am sure this is possible to do but I have no idea what such a system is called and where to look to get more information?

I mean I can easily compile the routines I want and program it on the MCU itself but I really want to make the things dynamic... Lets say I want to give this system to someone so he/she can easily do whatever he/she wants using custom scripts!

Comment: On bigger stm32 you can run lua interpreter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using stm32, upython can be a good option.

https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/grpl-upython.html#overview

List of features has mentioned "File system support (FAT) with custom block devices and transparent access from scripts".

It does support cortex-m4 and cortex-m7 stm32 devices.

Answer (score 4):

Embedded Lua is as times used as an interpreter on embedded systems to run a simple scripts.
Here is one implementation that has support for STM32: http://www.eluaproject.net/

Answer (score 1):

Yes you want to create the interpreter of your programming language. It is a very difficult task and interpreted languages are almost not used in the uC world.

Comment: Small special-purpose interpreters are not uncommon in the embedded world. I wrote a simple FORTH-like stack-based interpreter for writing to an LCD screen, for example, so that I could write text and variable values and draw lines and such. It's only about 300 lines of code in C and doesn't use much memory. I agree it's probably beyond the OP's level of skill, but it's not unthkinable.